# Database created in psql is not detected in PgAdmin 4

Tags: django, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I created a postgresql database named portfoliodb with user postgres using psql for my Django project. But when I use a PgAdmin the database doesn't show up there. Even when try to connect my database with django it says database not found.

But surprisingly when I create database with same name using PgAdmin everthing works fine and database gets connected to Django and all migrations are successful. Why is it so? Have I not properly installed Postgresql?

Now an intresting thing has come upon my notice. when I query version in command line it says:-
 PostgreSQL 9.5.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

on PgAdmin same query results:-
PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': 
        {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb',
        'USER': 'postgres'
        PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',  
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to provide more information, such as configuration of your django connector, database settings or any other information that would help people to reproduce the behavior your described. This will significantly improve your changes to get an answer ;-)

Comment: Maybe a missing commit?

Comment: I completely removed both the versions and freshly installed the problem was solved I am currently using PgAdmin3 which was by default present in ubuntu software center. Thankyou community for support!

Answer (score 2):

Please check that PostgreSQL database is running.

Try connect to your PostgreSQL database via command line:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U db_user db_name
```

It is possible that something went wrong, when you tried to create a database.

Worth a look:
[Create PostgreSQL database](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: psql: FATAL:  database "portfoliodb" does not exist. Also when ever I exit from psql it says:- could not save history to file "/opt/PostgreSQL/10/.psql_history": Permission denied

Comment: Try to display all of your existing databases.

Comment: I have only one db created for now it was freshly installed. I see that there are 2 versions of postgres 9.5 and 10

Comment: Yeah, I know, but try display it.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql/34419

Comment: I completely removed both the versions and freshly installed the problem was solved I am currently using PgAdmin3 which was by default present in ubuntu software center. Thankyou community for support!

Comment: Can you choose my answer as the best? Thanks !